# JQuery: Can't target h3 in same div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">

    <div class="row firstset">
        <h3 class="redtext">CLICK RED</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess green"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess red"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess blue"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess yellow"></div>
    </div><!--end of row-->

</div><!--end of col-->

<div class="col-xs-3">

    <div class="row secondset">
        <h3 class="greentext">CLICK GREEN</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess orange"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess purple"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess blue"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess green"></div>
    </div><!--end of row-->

</div><!--end of col-->
```

So I have about eight of these in total. Here is the JS.

JS:

```
$guess = $(".guess");

$guess.on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).siblings().find("h3").html());
});
```

When a div with class guess is clicked, I want to target the inner contents of the heading that the div is siblings with, but this method is giving me undefined. I even tried html(), but it doesn't work. How do I do this properly?

Comment: your code says find my siblings and look inside them for an h3.

Comment: you might try this https://jsfiddle.net/7L7ka2v4/

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `.find()`, that searches descendant elements. You only need to check siblings:

```
$guess.on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).siblings("h3").html());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mv4f381x/)**

Comment: This is a correct solution, but the real problem is that the jQuery chaining - `.sibling().find()` - put the poster in a different position in the DOM tree than expected. It'd be great if you included a little more information / pointers for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

just simply remove `.find()`as it use to get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.guess').click(function(){
console.log("using siblings "+$(this).siblings('h3').text());//no find needed
  console.log("using parent "+$(this).parent().find('h3').text());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-3">

    <div class="row firstset">
        <h3 class="redtext">CLICK RED</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess green">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess red">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess blue">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess yellow">1</div>
    </div><!--end of row-->

</div><!--end of col-->

<div class="col-xs-3">

    <div class="row secondset">
        <h3 class="greentext">CLICK GREEN</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess orange">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess purple">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess blue">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 guess green">1</div>
    </div><!--end of row-->

</div>
```

1. remove .find()
2. if you want to use .find() use .parent() instead of .siblings()